# raising subscript with mhchem

Tags: subscripts, mhchem

I've tried to define a macro with staggered sub- and superscript and added a formula with mhchem to the superscript. the typesetting seems misaligned especially the subscript seems to be typeseted to high. is there a way to fix this?
MWE:

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot,plain,ngerman,a4paper,12pt]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\va}[2]{$\nu_{\hspace{2px}\text{#2}}^\ce{\hspace{1px}#1}$}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\va{CO2}{as} \va{CO}{as} \va{CO2}{as} \va{CO}{as}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

the mwe output:

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth: with [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula)'s `\ch` this works “out of the box”: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\va}[2]{$\nu_{\,\text{#2}}^{\,\ch{#1}}$}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Smash the bottom of the exponent:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\va}[2]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \nu_{\,\text{#2}}%
       ^{\smash[b]{\ce{\,#1}}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\va{CO2}{as} \va{CO}{as} \va{CO2}{as} \va{CO}{as}
\va{O2}{asas}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this answer has a better typesetting. +1

Answer (score 3):

Add a custom strut below the baseline.  I also enclosed the `\ce` macro in braces to be on the safe side (thanks to Karl).

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot,plain,ngerman,a4paper,12pt]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\def\mystrut{\rule[-.15\baselineskip]{0pt}{1pt}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\va}[2]{$\nu_{\hspace{2px}\text{#2}}^{\ce{\hspace{1px}\mystrut#1}}$}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\va{CO2}{as} \va{CO}{as} \va{CO2}{as} \va{CO}{as}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't compile for me. It needs a pair of braces around `\ce{\hspace{1px}\mystrut#1}`

Comment: @karlkoeller I suppose one of us has a package out of date.  But enclosing it in braces is certainly the safe way to go, so I will edit the answer.

Comment: OK.................. :-)